# will both solutions fit in my example

Tags: past-tense

> I thought I had understood your answer but in fact **I had not**.

> I thought I had understood your answer but in fact **did not**.

I think "had not" is better because it relates to the verb "had understood", but does "did not" work as well?

Comment: The negation refers to understanding, not to thinking, so _had not_ is correct. You could say "I thought I understood... but I did not."

Comment: But if I say I thought I understood it is different because understood is almost on the same time frame than thought . I want to say that first I understood then i thought of it

Comment: No, at first you _thought_ that you understood, then you realised that you did not.

Comment: so there is no difference but I  thought  that as  I had backshifted  "understand"  it happens before . When a verb is backshifted it means that it happens first  isn't it

Comment: Exactly. I told you at first that _I thought I had understood, but I had not_ was correct. Then I gave an example of a sentence in which _did not_ would be appropriate.

Comment: i think I got it: when you say I thought I  understood your answer it means that  the belief of understanding lasted more  than when I say "I thought I had understood". I thought I had understood means   that my belief of understanding disappear very fast. So in my example I thought I understood would be better.

Comment: In practice, native speakers [rarely use the Perfect form](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+thought+I+understood%2CI+thought+I+had+understood&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20thought%20I%20understood%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20thought%20I%20had%20understood%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CI%20thought%20I%20understood%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20thought%20I%20had%20understood%3B%2Cc0) in this context. But I don't think this can affect the *meaning* - logically, my "understanding"  must precede my "thinking" that I understood, so there's only one possible meaning.

Answer (score 1):

The two sentences:

> - I thought I had understood your answer but in fact I had not.
> - I thought I had understood your answer but in fact did not.

have no significant difference in meaning. Both use the perfect form. As the comment by FumbleFingers  points out, (supported by the linked Ngram) this form is comparatively rare: A sentence  starting "I thought I understood your answer" would be much more likely.

One case where the perfect dorm woule be more likely would be:

> I thought I had understood your answer until I read Dumbledore's analysis.

But even there a simple past form (without the "had") would be more likely. But that wasn't really the question asked.

In practice the difference between "had not" and "did not" is only a matter of style here, whether a perfect or simple past is used.